# How do you git archive a branch using gzip with highest compression level?

Tags: git, ssh, zip, gzip, git-archive

I'm trying to git archive a branch using gzip with the highest level compression (9) but it seems to not compress at that level. Here is my command:

`` git -C /home/user/example.com/ archive --format tar -o /home/user/site_backups/develop-`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M`.tar develop | gzip -9 ``

It creates the tar file but the size is over 100MB compared to a zip that was compressed at 86MB using this command:

`` git -C /home/user/example.com/ archive --format zip -o /home/user/site_backups/develop-`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M`.zip develop ``

Can the output file be compressed more? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (4 years later), the command would be:

```
git -C /home/user/example.com/ archive --format tgz -19 -o /home/user/site_backups/develop-`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M`.tar develop
```

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ede4d63a2dbd4ed5477ce34872a808e99226230c/Documentation/git-archive.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> now allows compression level higher than "-9" when generating tar.gz output.

See [commit cde8ea9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cde8ea9c66e46ed6427499e0bc049d1d5c55379a) (09 Nov 2020) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ede4d63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ede4d63a2dbd4ed5477ce34872a808e99226230c), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`archive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cde8ea9c66e46ed6427499e0bc049d1d5c55379a): support compression levels beyond 9
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Compression programs like `zip`, `gzip`, `bzip2` and `xz` allow to adjust the trade-off between CPU cost and size gain with numerical options from `-1` for fast compression and `-9` for high compression ratio.
> zip also accepts `-0` for storing files verbatim.
> [`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cde8ea9c66e46ed6427499e0bc049d1d5c55379a/Documentation/git-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> directly support these single-digit compression levels for ZIP output and passes them to filters like gzip.
>
> Zstandard additionally supports compression level options `-10` to `-19`, or up to `-22` with `--ultra`.
> This *seems* to work with [`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cde8ea9c66e46ed6427499e0bc049d1d5c55379a/Documentation/git-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> in most cases, e.g. it will produce an archive with `-19` without complaining, but since it only supports single-digit compression level options this is the same as `-1 -9` and thus `-9`.
>
> Allow [`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cde8ea9c66e46ed6427499e0bc049d1d5c55379a/Documentation/git-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> to accept multi-digit compression levels to support the full range supported by `zstd`.
> Explicitly reject them for the ZIP format, as otherwise `deflateInit2()` would just fail with a somewhat cryptic "`stream consistency error`".

---

Note that, with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), "[`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b5a2d6cc49429132ba336c0c87f68f23dd1913b5/Documentation/git-archive.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> now (optionally and then by default) avoids spawning an external "`gzip`" process when creating "`.tar.gz`" (and "`.tgz`") archives.

See [commit 4f4be00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f4be00d302bc52d0d9d5a3d4738bb525066c710), [commit 23fcf8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23fcf8b09f5baee0a24bb39ad24263541333a759), [commit 76d7602](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76d7602631a9d0cb67cc1b848d580b862dc5de8b), [commit dfce118](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfce1186c6034d6f4ea283f5178fd25cbd8f4fc0), [commit 96b9e51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96b9e5151bf0cad110d2f0bf16f413b9fc9f606c), [commit 650134a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/650134a47894244b3804b5d175439b362453fa4a) (15 Jun 2022) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b5a2d6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5a2d6cc49429132ba336c0c87f68f23dd1913b5), 11 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`archive-tar`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76d7602631a9d0cb67cc1b848d580b862dc5de8b): add internal gzip implementation
>
> <sup>Original-patch-by: Rohit Ashiwal</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Git uses `zlib` for its own object store, but calls `gzip` when creating `tgz` archives.
>
> Add an option to perform the gzip compression for the latter using `zlib`, without depending on the external `gzip` binary.
>
> Plug it in by making `write_block` a function pointer and switching to a compressing variant if the filter command has the magic value "[`git archive gzip`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/76d7602631a9d0cb67cc1b848d580b862dc5de8b/Documentation/git-archive.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup>".
> Does that indirection slow down tar creation?  Not really, at least not in this test:
>
> ```
> $ hyperfine -w3 -L rev HEAD,origin/main -p 'git checkout {rev} && make' \
> ```

'./git -C ../linux archive --format=tar HEAD # {rev}'

> Benchmark #1: ./git -C ../linux archive --format=tar HEAD # HEAD
> Time (mean ± σ):      4.044 s ±  0.007 s    [User: 3.901 s, System: 0.137 s]
> Range (min … max):    4.038 s …  4.059 s    10 runs
>
> Benchmark #2: ./git -C ../linux archive --format=tar HEAD # origin/main
> Time (mean ± σ):      4.047 s ±  0.009 s    [User: 3.903 s, System: 0.138 s]
> Range (min … max):    4.038 s …  4.066 s    10 runs
>
> ```
> How does tgz creation perform?
> ```
>
> $ hyperfine -w3 -L command 'gzip -cn','git archive gzip' 
> './git -c tar.tgz.command="{command}" -C ../linux archive --format=tgz HEAD'
> Benchmark #1: ./git -c tar.tgz.command="gzip -cn" -C ../linux archive --format=tgz HEAD
> Time (mean ± σ):     20.404 s ±  0.006 s    [User: 23.943 s, System: 0.401 s]
> Range (min … max):   20.395 s … 20.414 s    10 runs
>
> Benchmark #2: ./`git -c` tar.tgz.command="git archive gzip -C ../linux archive --format=tgz HEAD
> Time (mean ± σ):     23.807 s ±  0.023 s    [User: 23.655 s, System: 0.145 s]
> Range (min … max):   23.782 s … 23.857 s    10 runs
>
> ```
> Summary
> ```
>
> ```
> './git -c tar.tgz.command="gzip -cn" -C ../linux archive --format=tgz HEAD' ran
>   1.17 ± 0.00 times faster than './git -c tar.tgz.command="git archive gzip" -C ../linux archive --format=tgz HEAD'
> ```
>
> ```
> So the internal implementation takes 17% longer on the Linux repo, but uses 2% less CPU time.  
> That's because the external gzip can run in parallel on its own processor, while the internal one works sequentially and avoids the inter-process communication overhead.  
>
> What are the benefits?
> ```

Only an internal sequential implementation can offer this eco mode, and it allows avoiding the `gzip(1)` requirement.

> This implementation uses the helper functions from our [`zlib.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/76d7602631a9d0cb67cc1b848d580b862dc5de8b/zlib.c) instead of the convenient `gz*` functions from `zlib`, because the latter doesn't give the control over the generated gzip header that the next patch requires.

And:

> ### [`archive-tar`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f4be00d302bc52d0d9d5a3d4738bb525066c710): use internal gzip by default
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Drop the dependency on gzip(1) and use our internal implementation to create `tar.gz` and `tgz` files.

`git archive` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4f4be00d302bc52d0d9d5a3d4738bb525066c710/Documentation/git-archive.txt#L151-L152):

> magic command `git archive gzip` by default, which invokes an *internal* implementation of gzip.

So a `git archive` using an *external* gzip would be:

```
git -c tar.tgz.command="gzip -cn" archive --format=tgz HEAD >external_gzip.tgz
```

While the new default one would use the internal zlib:

```
git archive --format=tgz HEAD >j.tgz
```

In both cases, the compression level options mentioned above still apply.